# Trying to use DropDownListFor with ASP.Net. Why is this erroring out?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple model

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Month{ get; set;}

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Months
    {
        get
        {
            return new[] { new SelectListItem{ Text="Jan",Value="1" } };
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to display this on a page using `DropDownListFor` like this

```
@model ViewModels.MyModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Month, new SelectList(Model.Months,"Text","Value"))
```

When I build and run this I get and error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
If I have a property in my class that is a simple string I can use `LabelFor(m=>m.TestString)` and it displays that correctly so I know the model exists.
What am I missing?

TIA

Comment: it should work .   m=>m.Month

Comment: Your code should work, can you show your controller action?

Comment: Did you instantiate your ViewModel and passed it to View()? Can you show your action in the controller that is supposed to return this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your types are are not matching. In your model you need to do the following:

```
public SelectList Months
{
   get
   {
        var monthNames = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames.Take(12).ToList();
        return new SelectList(monthNames.Select(m => new {Id = monthNames.IndexOf(m) + 1, Name = m}).ToList(), "Id", "Name");
   }
```

}

then in your view all you need is:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Month, Model.Months)
```

Also make sure your model is instantiated and not null.

Answer (score 1):

it should work . `m=>m.Month`

and
on controller

```
MyModel model=new MyModel();
return View(model);
```